# Implementing the Python Multiprocessing Module for Real-Time Speaker Identification

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am developing an algorithm for real-time speaker identification. My idea was to run three tasks, namely `writeAudio()`, `detectionBlock()`, and `identificationBlock()`, in parallel using the `multiprocessing` module.

In effect, the `writeAudio()` function uses `PyAudio` to capture a continuous recording and save the 0.5-second audio files to a local directory, the `detectionBlock()` function processes the two oldest 0.5-second files from the directory and uses a Voice Activity Detection (VAD) model to determine if the audio is speech or noise, and the `identificationBlock()` function processes a separate 3-second audio file (saved to a different directory from a chunk of 0.5-second audio files) and then uses a Voice Recognition (VR) model to determine the speaker's identity.

I was hoping that I could apply `multiprocessing` here to sidestep the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and run the three functions simultaneously as `Process` objects. Currently, the program won't start running the `detectionBlock()` or `identificationBlock()` functions until after `writeAudio()` has finished recording.

Here's the code for the current implementation with `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

# Perform Parallel Processing with the Multiprocessing Module
    def parallelProcessing(self):
        
        # Define Individual Functions as Process() Objects
        rec = Process(target=self.writeAudio()) # Cog 1
        vad = Process(target=self.detectionBlock()) # Cog 2
        si = Process(target=self.identificationBlock()) # Cog 3
        
        cogs = [rec, vad, si] # List of functions
        
        # Run All Three Cogs in Parallel
        rec.start() # Start Cog 1
        
        time.sleep(3) # Wait 3 sec to start speech detection & identification
 
        vad.start() # Start Cog 2
        si.start() # Start Cog 3
        
        for cog in cogs:
            cog.join() # Wait for processes to complete before continuing
```

I've never applied `multiprocessing` before, so I was wondering if this would be feasible with a different implementation approach. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

I've added simplified versions of the functions below for enhanced clarity.

```
# Speech Detection Sequence
    def detectionBlock(self):
        
        # Create VoiceActivityDetectionModel() Class Object
        vad = VoiceActivityDetectionModel()
        
        # Run Speech Detection on Oldest Audio Segments in Directory
        files = self.getListDir() # List of audiofiles
        index = 0 # First file in list
        
        path_1 = os.path.join(self.VAD_audio_path, files[index])
        path_2 = os.path.join(self.VAD_audio_path, files[index+1])
        
        label_1, _, _ = vad.detectFromAudiofile(path_1) # VAD classifier for first segment
        label_2, _, _ = vad.detectFromAudiofile(path_2) # VAD classifier for second segment
        
        if (label_1 == 'speech') and (label_2 == 'speech'):
            self.combineAudio(index) # Generate 3-sec recording for SI if 
                                     # speech is detected in both audiofiles
        else:
            self.deleteAudio() # Remove oldest audio segment
```

```
    # Speaker Identification Sequence
    def identificationBlock(self):
        
        # Create EnsemblePredictions() Class Object
        ep = EnsemblePredictions()
        
        # Run Speaker Identification on Oldest Audio Segment in Directory
        files = self.getListDir(audio_type='SI')
        index = 0 # First file in list
        
        if files:
            filepath = os.path.join(self.SI_audio_path, files[index])
        
            speaker, prob_list = ep.predict(filepath, first_session=False) # SI classifier
            time_stamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime()) # Time of identification
        
            self.speakerDiarization(speaker=speaker, prob_list=prob_list, time_stamp=time_stamp) # Save results
        
            # Remove 3-Second Audio Segment from Directory
            self.deleteAudio(audio_type='SI')
```

```
# Audio Recording Sequence
    def writeAudio(self):
        
        # Instantiate Recording System Variables
        FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32 # 32 bits per sample
        CHANNELS = 1 # Mono
        RATE = 16000 # Sampling Rate
        CHUNK = int(self.VAD_audio_length*RATE) # Chunks of bytes to record from microphone
        
        # Initialize Recording
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio() # Create interface to PortAudio

        input('Press ENTER to Begin Recording') # Wait for keypress to record

        if keyboard.is_pressed('Enter'):
            stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                            channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE,
                            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                            input=True)
            
            print()
            print('Hold SPACE to Finish Recording')
            
            while(True):
                # End Process with Manual User Interrupt
                if keyboard.is_pressed('Space'):
                    break 
                
                # Generate Audio Recording
                data = stream.read(CHUNK) # Read 0.5-second segment from audio stream
                data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32) # Convert to NumPy array
                
                filename = 'VAD_segment_' + str(self.VAD_audio_count) + '.wav'
                
                sf.write(os.path.join(self.VAD_audio_path, filename), data, RATE)
        
                # Adjust Segment Count
                self.VAD_audio_count = self.VAD_audio_count + 1 # Increment
                
            # Stop & Close Stream
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
        
            # Terminate PortAudio Interface
            p.terminate()
```

Comment: can you share a simplified version of the three target functions? there's not a lot to go on based on what you posted...

Comment: as a side note, you can use a library like `pastream` to simplify life, and cut down the number of processes because recording will happen in a separate thread where the GIL is released. I would then do the `detectionBlock` work in the main thread via the callbacks of chunks of data from `pastream`, and send chunks of audio to a child process whenever sound is detected. I'd skip the filesystem for speed and latency, and because 3 sec of uncompressed audio should easily fit in memory.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the help. I'll look into `pastream`. Just added the three target functions when you get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I mentioned in the comments. I don't have all the components to actually run it, so treat it a bit like pseudocode, but I believe it should be a good jumping off point. The main improvement is a bit of simplification courtesy of `pastream` which claims basically GIL-less `portaudio` iteration. The benefit here is less overhead and easier transfer of data to at least the first stage in the pipeline which is detecting audio. You may need some additional complexity to drop frames in the event of a slowdown, but this structure should generally work provided I understood the `pastream` docs correctly.

```py
import pastream
import multiprocessing as mp
from Queue import Empty

class ExitFlag: pass

def voice_identification(rx_q: mp.Queue):
    while True:
        try:
            received = rx_q.get(1) 
            #if voice_identification is too slow you may want to `get` until 
            #  the queue is empty to drop all but most recent frame. This way
            #  you won't have an infinitely growing queue.
        except Empty:
            pass
        if isinstance(received, ExitFlag):
            break
        
        else:
            print(identify(received)) #identify audio
    print("identifier process exiting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tx_q = mp.Queue()
    identifier_p = mp.Process(target=voice_identification, args=(tx_q,))
    identifier_p.start()
    
    samplerate=44100
    stream = pastream.InputStream()
    #3 second chunks every half second
    for chunk in stream.chunks(chunksize=samplerate/2, overlap=(samplerate/2)*5):
        if detect_audio(chunk): #detect audio
            tx_q.put(chunk)
        if exit_key_down(): #however you want to detect this, it's good to ensure smooth shutdown of child
            tx_q.put(ExitFlag())
            identifier_p.join()
            break
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I've successfully implemented it. The only issue is that the `voice_identification` child process is unable to print. I tried adding `sys.stdout.flush` to force everything in the buffer to the terminal window; however, that didn't seem to work. Do you potentially know of another solution?

Comment: @Zack sometimes sdtout gets mangled by IDE's are you running from terminal? Also child could possibly crash silently. I don't remember at the moment all the exception forwarding details...

Comment: I'm running from the Spyder IDE, but I'll try running from terminal and see if that makes a difference. Thanks